# Estimating a curve integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuously differentiable curve with $f(z) \le \lvert C \rvert$ for all $z \in U$ and some constant $C$. Let further be $\gamma:[t_0,t_1] \rightarrow U$ a continuously differentiable curve. Prove that
>
> $$\bigg\lvert \int_\gamma f(z)dz \bigg\rvert \le L(\gamma) \cdot C$$
>
> , where $L(\gamma)$ is the length of the curve $\gamma$.

I tried the direct approach. I used that
$$ L(\gamma)  := \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \lvert \dot{\gamma} \rvert dt$$
and tried to arrive at this estimation by real analysis:

\begin{align}
\bigg\lvert \int_\gamma f(z)dz \bigg\rvert &= \bigg\lvert \int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(\gamma(t))\cdot \dot{\gamma}(t) dt \bigg\rvert \\
&= \Bigg\lvert   \dot{\gamma}(t) \cdot \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathcal{Re}(f(\gamma(t))) dt+ i \cdot \dot{\gamma}(t) \cdot \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathcal{Im}(f(\gamma(t))) dt \ \Bigg\rvert
\end{align}

I wanted to use the triangle inequality on this, but it does not work out. I suppose there is some kind of trick. Could you help me?

Comment: Its simpler: $\left\lvert \int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(\gamma(t))\cdot \dot{\gamma}(t) dt \right\rvert \le  \int_{t_0}^{t_1}| f(\gamma(t))\cdot \dot{\gamma}(t) |dt $

Comment: Use that $|f\circ \gamma|$ is continuous on the compact set $[t_0,t_1]$ and $\int_{\gamma}|dz|=L_{\gamma}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that\begin{align}\left\lvert\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz\right\rvert&\leqslant\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\bigl\lvert f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\bigr\rvert.\bigl\lvert\gamma'(t)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dt\\&\leqslant C\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\bigl\lvert\gamma'(t)\bigr\rvert\,\mathrm dt\\&=C\times L(\gamma).\end{align}